# Trying to implement camera permissions for android M getting No virtual method checkSelfPermission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I tried implementing camera permissions in this way:

```
private void checkCameraPermissions() {
        if(checkCameraHardware(this)) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission_group.camera)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Crashlytics.log("Requesting camera permission");

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        Manifest.permission_group.camera)) {
                    // Explain to the user why we need to use the camera
                    showRationaleForCameraUse();
                }

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission_group.camera},
                        Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA_GROUP);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA_GROUP is an
                // app-defined int constant
            } else {
                startApp();
            }
        }else{
            showNoCameraAvailableAlert();
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA_GROUP: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay!
                    // start the app
                    startApp();

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo!
                    // leav the app!
                    showNoCameraAvailableAlert();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'switch' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

and got this following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method checkSelfPermission(Ljava/lang/String;)I in class Lim/emu/app/emu/app/view/splash/SplashActivity; or its super classes (declaration of 'im.emu.app.emu.app.view.splash.SplashActivity' appears in /data/app/im.emu.app.emu.test-1/base.apk)
            at im.emu.app.emu.app.view.splash.SplashActivity.checkCameraPermissions(SplashActivity.java:74)
            at im.emu.app.emu.app.view.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
08-30 16:34:10.801  17087-17357/im.emu.app.emu.test I/Fabric﹕ Crashlytics report upload complete: 55E30629033A-0001-42BF-296ED8AC703A.cls
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?
p.s. if any more information is needed please ask

Comment: Beyond the problem cited in Derek Fung's answer, `checkSelfPermission()`, `requestPermission()`, and kin take the name of a *permission* (e.g., `Manifest.permission.CAMERA`), not a permission group. FWIW, [this directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/tutorial) contains before-and-after editions of an app that uses the camera, where the "after" edition checks for Android 6.0 runtime permissions. I am not using `ContextCompat` only because I wrote the tutorial for the M Developer Preview, before the `ContextCompat` stuff existed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be running the code on device running previous versions. You have to use `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` instead.

Comment: so should I check if I am on android M and only use "ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()" when I am not on M? Or use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() all the time?

Comment: just always use `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`, it will handle all cases for you. Behind the scene, it check which whether it is on M and call the actual function, if it is before M it just return true, something like this.

Comment: Thanks! it actually says this here: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html under "Support library methods for handling permissions". shame on me for not reading all the way through...

Answer (score 2):

Careful with

```
'shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        Manifest.permission_group.camera)'
```

I had an issue with the permissions group where it wanted the individual permission and not the group and would throw an exception if you used the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()` instead for backward capability on Pre-Lollipop devices. So `this.checkSelfPermission()` can be used only for apps which declares `minSdkVersion 23`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```